# statsmodels.tsa.api-0.9.0 ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels

Code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels as sm
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing, SimpleExpSmoothing, Holt

print('statsmodels.__version__', sm.__version__)

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [547.184518,  256.990247,  237.709566,  465.214791,  1479.401737],
], columns=['point_4', 'point_5', 'point_6', 'point_7', 'point_8'], index=['000001.XSHE'])

fit2 = SimpleExpSmoothing(df.loc['000001.XSHE']).fit(smoothing_level=0.6, optimized=False)
fcast1 = fit2.forecast(1)
```

Error:

```
statsmodels.__version__ 0.9.0
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/tsa_model.py:221: ValueWarning: An unsupported index was provided and will be ignored when e.g. forecasting.
  ' ignored when e.g. forecasting.', ValueWarning)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-a742c2be4f46> in <module>
     12 ], columns=['point_4', 'point_5', 'point_6', 'point_7', 'point_8'], index=['000001.XSHE'])
     13 
---> 14 fit2 = SimpleExpSmoothing(df.loc['000001.XSHE']).fit(smoothing_level=0.6, optimized=False)
     15 fcast1 = fit2.forecast(1)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/holtwinters.py in fit(self, smoothing_level, optimized)
    814         [1] Hyndman, Rob J., and George Athanasopoulos. Forecasting: principles and practice. OTexts, 2014.
    815         """
--> 816         return super(SimpleExpSmoothing, self).fit(smoothing_level=smoothing_level, optimized=optimized)
    817 
    818 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/holtwinters.py in fit(self, smoothing_level, smoothing_slope, smoothing_seasonal, damping_slope, optimized, use_boxcox, remove_bias, use_basinhopping)
    592                               smoothing_seasonal=gamma, damping_slope=phi,
    593                               initial_level=l0, initial_slope=b0, initial_seasons=s0,
--> 594                               use_boxcox=use_boxcox, lamda=lamda, remove_bias=remove_bias)
    595         hwfit._results.mle_retvals = opt
    596         return hwfit

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/holtwinters.py in _predict(self, h, smoothing_level, smoothing_slope, smoothing_seasonal, initial_level, initial_slope, damping_slope, initial_seasons, use_boxcox, lamda, remove_bias)
    733         k = m * seasoning + 2 * trending + 2 + 1 * damped
    734         aic = self.nobs * np.log(sse / self.nobs) + (k) * 2
--> 735         aicc = aic + (2 * (k + 2) * (k + 3)) / (self.nobs - k - 3)
    736         bic = self.nobs * np.log(sse / self.nobs) + (k) * np.log(self.nobs)
    737         resid = data - fitted[:-h - 1]

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

`SimpleExpSmoothing` is used for forcasting time series based data, my input data is valid, it should output forecast data without error.

If I remove `point_8` column from the DataFrame, then the error disappears.

Do you know why it throws `ZeroDivisionError`?

Comment: This version is totally unsupported.  There have been many changes to this method since then and I really suggest that you upgrade to 0.12.2 if at all possible.

Comment: Could someone tell me why this topic is closed? It has code and error message, what else do you what me to post?

Comment: While I didn't close it, it might have been closed due to the unsupported nature of statsmodels 0.9.